# Script to prefix filename with folder

Tags: windows, command-line, script, perl

I am trying to find a script that will work in Windows and prefix all files in a folder with the containing folder name.

For example, in the folder `C:\FolderName1` there are 3 files:

```
hello.jpg
test.txt
monday.docx
```

After the script has been run for the above files, the names will be as follows:

```
FolderName1 - hello.jpg
FolderName1 - test.txt
FolderName1 - monday.docx
```

I don't mind which scripting language this is in, but I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

How many folders are there? If just one, you may rename all files with single `for` loop:

1. Create `C:\FolderName1_out` folder
2. Open CMD prompt
3. `for %I in (C:\FolderName1\*) do echo rename "C:\FolderName1\%~nxI" "C:\FolderName1_out\FolderName1 - %~nxI"`
4. If rename plan seems right, remove `echo` from the command above and run again

If there are many folders, then you may create batch file (replace all % with %% and FolderName1 with %1) and run it multiple times, passing folder name as argument. You may even run that batch file in the for loop:

`for /D %J in (*) do echo call my_batch.cmd %~nxJ`

If output seems right, then remove `echo` and run again.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell. If you need to change file names only in one folder then use this:

```
gci c:\PathToFolder | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " - " + $_.Name}
```

It changes all files in that folder (but excludes folders from renaming) to format *PathToFolder - Filename*

You can add `-Recurse` if you have nested folders:

```
gci c:\PathToParentFolder -Recurse | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " - " + $_.Name}
```

Be sure to run on a test folder first or just add `-WhatIf` to the end of the command to see the potential results without actually destroying your data :)